# how to verify number of disks in RAID but from OS

Tags: rhel, hard-disk, disk, smartctl, dmidecode

we have Linux RHEL server - `7.6` version

in server disks are :

```
lsblk -S
NAME HCTL       TYPE VENDOR   MODEL             REV TRAN
sda  0:2:0:0    disk DELL     PERC FD33xD      4.27
sdb  1:0:0:0    disk ATA      INTEL SSDSC1BG40 DL2B sata
sdc  2:0:0:0    disk ATA      INTEL SSDSC1BG40 DL2B sata
```

sdc and sdb are the OS disks

about `sda` is disk that represented by RAID

so `sda` include number of disks , but the question is how to count the number of disks in RAID

we tried the following but we not sure if this cli described the number of disks in RAID?

```
smartctl --scan
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device
/dev/sdb -d scsi # /dev/sdb, SCSI device
/dev/sdc -d scsi # /dev/sdc, SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,0 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_00], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,1 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_01], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,2 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_02], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,3 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_03], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,4 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_04], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,5 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_05], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,6 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_06], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,7 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_07], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,8 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_08], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,9 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_09], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,10 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_10], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,11 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_11], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,12 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_12], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,13 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_13], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,14 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_14], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,15 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_15], SCSI device


lspci -vv | grep -i raid
06:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS-3 3108 [Invader] (rev 02)
        Kernel driver in use: megaraid_sas

 mdadm --detail /dev/sda
mdadm: /dev/sda does not appear to be an md device


 cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md1 : active raid1 sdb2[0] sdc2[1]
      390054912 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 2/3 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sdb1[0] sdc1[1]
      524224 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>

lsscsi
[0:2:0:0]    disk    DELL     PERC FD33xD      4.27  /dev/sda
[1:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      INTEL SSDSC1BG40 DL2B  /dev/sdb
[2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      INTEL SSDSC1BG40 DL2B  /dev/sdc




   cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0 13670809600 sda
   8       16  390711384 sdb
   8       17     524288 sdb1
   8       18  390185984 sdb2
   8       32  390711384 sdc
   8       33     524288 sdc1
   8       34  390185984 sdc2
   9        0     524224 md0
   9        1  390054912 md1
 253        0  104857600 dm-0
 253        1   16777216 dm-1
 253        2  104857600 dm-2
 253        3   10485760 dm-3



 ll /sys/block/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 17 07:27 dm-0 -> ../devices/virtual/block/dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 17 07:27 dm-1 -> ../devices/virtual/block/dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 17 07:27 dm-2 -> ../devices/virtual/block/dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 17 07:27 dm-3 -> ../devices/virtual/block/dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 17 07:27 md0 -> ../devices/virtual/block/md0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 17 07:27 md1 -> ../devices/virtual/block/md1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 17 07:27 sda -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:01.0/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:01.0/0000:06:00.0/host0/target0:2:0/0:2:0:0/block/sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 17 07:27 sdb -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.4/ata1/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 17 07:27 sdc -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.4/ata2/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdc


ll /sys/block/ |grep 'primary'

no output
```

Comment: what is the output of the `cat /proc/partitions`?

Comment: I update the Question with results of commands

Comment: please add also `ll /sys/block/ |grep 'primary'`, the output would be the number of disks in the RAID

Comment: Question was update

Comment: It's been years since I did this, but should the commands not be `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` and `mdadm --detail /dev/md1`?

Comment: yes but I am talking about sda (  as I understand md0 and md1 are related to OS disk - sdb and adc )   , so what I want to get is about sda that actually build from RAID and include number of disks

Comment: You have things round the wrong way. Why not just try the command. The raid devices `/dev/mdX` are built from the system disks, `/dev/sdXX`.

Comment: Some hardware RAID controllers (all the DELL servers we've bought at my work in the last several years have had those) present their output in a way that makes Linux present them as `/dev/sdX`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `mdadm` command will handle Linux Software RAID *only*. In case of hardware RAID, such as your Dell PERC FD33xD / LSI MegaRAID SAS-3 3108, you'll need a tool that will be able to communicate with the RAID controller using vendor-specific protocols to query the information.

Unfortunately, since the ownership of that RAID controller product line has passed from Symbios to LSI to Avago to (current) Broadcom, it can be quite difficult to find the management tools for some RAID controller models from the original equipment manufacturer.

But Dell is actually supporting a version of the management tool, known as `perccli`, for their branded versions of the RAID controllers. But you apparently cannot use an identifier like "PERC FD33xD" or "LSI MegaRAID SAS-3 3108" to search for drivers on Dell's support site: you need either the name of a server model that contains the RAID controller in question, or some Dell product name or support identifier that unfortunately won't appear in `lsblk`/`lsscsi`/`lspci` outputs.

By some quick Googling, it appears that "PowerEdge FD332" is one of the models that might contain that RAID controller. So go to [Dell support page](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/?app=products), type in "PowerEdge FD332" (or your actual Dell server model, if applicable) and select "Drivers & Downloads".

You'll see a box titled with "Find a driver for your PowerEdge FD332" (or whatever model you picked) with four drop-down menus. From the "Operating System" drop-down, pick your operating system, "RedHat Enterprise Linux 7" in this case. Then from the "Category" drop-down, pick "SAS RAID". And the list of downloadable drivers updates, and somewhere near the top (currently the very first entry for me!) should be "Linux PERCCLI Utility for all Dell HBA/PERC controllers". Download and install it: it will be a `.tar.gz` package containing both a `.rpm` file for RedHat and other distributions, and a `.deb` file for Debian and related distributions.

After that, you should have the tool available in the `/opt/MegaCLI/perccli/` directory, as either `perccli` or `perccli64`.

The first command you should use with the tool should probably be:

```
/opt/MegaCLI/perccli/perccli64 /show
```

This will display the installed compatible RAID controllers and identify the numbers this tool will use for each. If there is just one RAID controller, it presumably is number 0.

To get the list of actual physical disks from RAID controller #0:

```
/opt/MegaCLI/perccli/perccli64 /c0 /eall /sall show all
```

The list should look similar to this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG      Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                  Sp 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:0     7 Onln   0 465.25 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD5003ABYX-01WERA1 U  
252:1     6 Onln   1 465.25 GB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD5003ABYX-01WERA1 U  
252:2     5 Onln   2   74.0 GB SATA SSD N   N  512B INTEL SSDSC2BB080G4    U  
252:3     4 Onln   2   74.0 GB SATA SSD N   N  512B INTEL SSDSC2BB080G4    U  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

EID-Enclosure Device ID|Slt-Slot No.|DID-Device ID|DG-DriveGroup
DHS-Dedicated Hot Spare|UGood-Unconfigured Good|GHS-Global Hotspare
UBad-Unconfigured Bad|Onln-Online|Offln-Offline|Intf-Interface
Med-Media Type|SED-Self Encryptive Drive|PI-Protection Info
SeSz-Sector Size|Sp-Spun|U-Up|D-Down|T-Transition|F-Foreign
UGUnsp-Unsupported
```

The numbers in the **DID column** are the numbers you can use with the `smartctl` command, e.g.

```
smartctl -a -d megaraid,<DID value> /dev/sda
```

Reference: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Smartmontools_with_MegaRAID_Controller

---

Note: Older and/or non-Dell-specific versions of these tools used to be known as `MegaCLI` and/or `storcli`, but those seem to be behind a labyrinth of stale web links and revised product naming schemes. The only link for MegaRAID SAS-3 3108 Linux tools on Broadcom's pages I managed to find currently points to a page in avago.com that no longer exists.

So, I say this based on my 20 years of experience with enterprise-grade computer hardware: if you have systems with hardware RAID controllers, **make sure you download any vendor-specific controller configuration tools** from the vendor support site when initially setting up the server, and **save them**. And even if you have no problems with the controller, **check for updates** once in a while.

If the product line is sold to a different company or the hardware vendor simply decides that their support site needs a new design, some tools may go missing for a while: in the case of RAID controller configuration tools, it is indeed very much better to have them and not need them, than vice versa.

If you are planning to use old server models beyond their vendor support lifetime **for any reason** (even as test servers only!), make sure you **download all the applicable vendor-specific tools and drivers** before the end-of-support date, and **archive them in a safe location**. After the support ends, the downloads may vanish from the vendor's website without any warning.

Comment: +1. Also worth noting, there's really no benefit to using hardware raid on Linux these days (especially for raid-1 or raid-10, there's still some value in HW raid with non-volatile write cache for raid-5/6). It's probably not worth the effort (and down-time) to convert from HW raid to software raid, but for building a new system or rebuilding an old system it's generally a better idea to use software raid with mdadm, LVM, ZFS, or btrfs - doing this when drives are connected to a HW RAID controller, it would need to be configured to to present each drive individually to the host OS (i.e. JBOD).

Comment: also note: some HW RAID controllers don't have a JBOD mode, or achieve it clumsily by requiring you to set up a single drive "RAID array" for each individual drive.

Answer (score 0):

When you read

```
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[0] sdc1[1]
      524224 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

In `[2/2]`, the first 2 is the number of active disks used for the RAID, the second, the number of disk which should be active to avoid a degraded RAID.

Comment: yes but I am asking aboutr /dev/sda - ( about sdb and sdb we know that disks in TAID )   , sda disk is for sure in RAID but from OS we saw of coerce only one disk

Comment: I guess I gave not understood the question. Note, you wrote _ so sda include number of disks _. No sda is a single disk. It contains multiple partitions. Using the exact terms makes it easier to understand what you want.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer Unfortunately with some hardware RAID controllers, that is not always true. A true hardware RAID controller may present a single logical device as `/dev/sda`, and hide the fact that it actually is a RAID set of multiple disks. Only by communicating with the RAID controller using vendor-specific protocols, you will be able to get information of the actual disks.